# Is there a way to make Resharper 4.5 understand a multi-line TODO or NOTE?

Tags: resharper-4.5

Is there a way to make Resharper 4.5 understand a multi-line TODO or NOTE?

For example, this will show up as two items in the TODO explorer:

```
    // NOTE: Because of the external dependency, this method is particularly bug-prone.
    // NOTE: Once we've adopted automated testing, we could get some nice testing for this stuff using a repository to mock an actual account.
```

Is there a way to make it show up as a single item without writing it on one really long line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiline TODO's in Resharper 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921483/how-to-get-multiline-todos-in-resharper-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not look like you can. Even the ReSharper 5 beta does not color code multi-line TODO or NOTE comments the way you would want.

I suggest that you [open an enhancement ticket with JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=ReSharper&ask=Suggestion).

Comment: You can do this with an altered regex as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921629/342594).