# How to write multiline todos in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to write todo items (which will show up in the task list of VS) over more than one line. Something like that:

```
//TODO: This is a todo over
// more than one line!
```

**Is there any way to do it?**

I use ReSharper, too, if it's important.

Comment: Not sure about this, but have a look at [Using a ToDo list more effectively](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/25/using-a-todo-list-more-effectively/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get multiline TODO's in Resharper 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921483/how-to-get-multiline-todos-in-resharper-8)

Comment: Its 2021 and this is still something I want in VS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately it's **not** possible to mark a multiple-line TODO.

This was already [asked a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970103/is-there-a-way-to-make-resharper-4-5-understand-a-multi-line-todo-or-note) and still doesn't look like something has changed.

You could ask the JetBrains support, if they will change something about this.